# Converter hora PHP

Tags: php

Pretendo converter a hora que recebo que vem de uma input time (01:00) para o formato "his" que quero que o resultado seja 010000. Utilizei este código, funcionou mas da erro de notice.

```
$hour=date("his",$txthourstart);
```

Como posso converter para esse formato?

Comment: Você usou o strtotime() para converter o valor?

Comment: Não, é preciso converter?

Comment: É recomendável, porque a atribuição direta de uma string irá causar erros na interpretação dos dados.

Comment: Utilizei $hora=strtotime($txthourstart); mas caso tenho 23:00, mete a 110000. Queria que o resultado fosse 230000.

Comment: Então use "His". O caractere "H" representa o formato em 24 horas, enquanto o "h" o representa em 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefira utilizar os métodos e classes providos pelo PHP para utilizar a interpretação dos dados temporais. Existem duas soluções principais:

Orientada a Objetos (>= PHP 5.2)

```
$hourStart = DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i", $txthourstart);
$hour = $hourStart->format('His');
```

Procedural

```
$hour = date("His", strtotime($txthourstart));
```